# Configure cabal upload to work with local hackage-server

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

I have a local hackage-server installed for development at `192.168.1.100:8080`. After I develop, and package a package with `cabal sdist` I have to head to `192.168.1.100:8080` on my browser and manually upload the package.

This is extremely tedious, especially during a sprint like situation when multiple packages are being worked on etc, and I would just love to use `cabal upload`.

For a package called my-pacakge.tar.gz, running `cabal upload` results in a:

```
Uploading dist/my-package-0.1.1.0.tar.gz...
Error: dist/my-package-0.1.1.0.tar.gz: 404 Not Found
Error: Page not found

Sorry, it's just not here.
```

The modified portion of my cabal config looks as follows:

```
...    
remote-repo: hackage.haskell.org:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive
remote-repo: my.hackage:http://192.168.1.100:8080/packages/archive
...
```

The second line prioritizes the local hackage over hackage.haskell for `cabal install`

How should I set `cabal upload` to upload to the local hackage?

Answer (score 0):

The remote repo should be configured as

`remote-repo: my-hackage:http://my-hackage.com:8080/`

I.e. no `/packages/archive`. The extra path only works as a hack on the main server to match old-style paths (pre-hackage 2.0).

(c.f. https://github.com/haskell/hackage-server/issues/164)